# How to show the progress percentage in the middle center of a ProgressBar?

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I tried to use a Label, this is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly ProgressBar _progressBar;
    private readonly Label _labelProgress;
    private readonly Timer downloadTimer;
    private readonly Radar radar;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _httpClient = new HttpClient();

        _progressBar = new ProgressBar
        {
            Size = lblNextTimeDownload.Size,
            Minimum = 0,
            Maximum = 100,
            Value = 0,
        };

        _labelProgress = new Label
        {
            AutoSize = false,
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
            Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular),
        };

        _progressBar.Controls.Add(_labelProgress);
        Controls.Add(_progressBar);
    }
}
```

The result is that the `_labelProgress` is positioned at the top left on the ProgressBar

[image: label is on top left of the progressBar]

If in the Label's instance I add the line:

```
Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
```

like this:

```
_labelProgress = new Label
{
    AutoSize = false,
    TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
    Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular),
};
```

then the text  of the Label is positioned in the center middle of the ProgresBar, but it also overlaps the entire ProgressBar.

[image: no progressbar display because the label is docked fill]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to avoid using a Label for this. Among other things, you may find out that it doesn't scale the same way as the ProgressBar, when your Form is scaled in a DpiAware context.

You can directly paint the percentage onto the Control's surface, using the ProgressBar's DC. Override WndProc and handle `WM_PAINT` for this.

Of course, you need to build a Custom Control, override it's WndProc, trap `WM_PAINT`, then use [GetWindowDc()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowdc) to get its device context.
`Graphics.FromHdcInternal()` is then called to generate a Graphics object, which is then passed to `TextRenderer.DrawText()` to render the percentage as text.

[ReleaseDC()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-releasedc) must be called after, to release the HDC.

[image: ProgressBar with percentage]

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[ToolboxItem(true), DesignerCategory("code")]
public class ProgressBarEx : ProgressBar {
    Color percentageColor = Color.Black;
    int percentageDecimals = 0;
    public ProgressBarEx() { }

    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Black")]
    public Color PercentageColor { 
        get => percentageColor; 
        set { 
            if (percentageColor != value) {
                percentageColor = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        } 
    }

    [DefaultValue(0), Description("Number of decimals (0-4)")]
    public int PercentageDecimals {
        get => percentageDecimals;
        set { 
            if (percentageDecimals != value) {
                percentageDecimals = Math.Max(Math.Min(value, 4), 0);
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        switch (m.Msg) {
            case WM_PAINT:
                if (!IsHandleCreated) return;
                float percentage = (float)Value / Maximum;
                percentage = float.IsNaN(percentage) ? 0 : percentage;
                var hDC = GetWindowDC(this.Handle);
                try {
                    using (var g = Graphics.FromHdcInternal(hDC)) {
                        TextRenderer.DrawText(g, percentage.ToString($"P{percentageDecimals}"), 
                            Font, ClientRectangle, percentageColor);
                    }
                }
                finally {
                    if (hDC != IntPtr.Zero) ReleaseDC(this.Handle, hDC);
                }
                m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    const int WM_PAINT = 0x000F;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDc);
}
```