# Why when trying to download files and trying to get the files sizes if the files sizes are 0 or less then 0 it's showing NaN on the progressBaeEx2?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the method where I'm trying to get each file size before downloading the files:

```
private async Task<long> GetFileSizeAsync(Uri uri)
{
    try
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, uri)))
            {
                if (response.Headers.Contains("Content-Length") &&
                    long.TryParse(response.Headers.GetValues("Content-Length").FirstOrDefault(), out long contentLength))
                {
                    return contentLength;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        // Log or handle the exception as needed
        Console.WriteLine($"Error getting file size: {ex.Message}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle other types of exceptions if necessary
        Console.WriteLine($"An unexpected error occurred: {ex.Message}");
    }

    // Return a default value if unable to get the file size
    return -1;
}
```

and then inside the button click event btnDownload_Click I'm checking if the value in the variable totalBytesToReceive is more then 0 then update the progressBarEx2 but if not then set the progressBarEx2 to 0 but it keep showing on the progressBarEx2 value the text NaN

before adding this check of the totalBytesToReceive the progressBarEx2 reached to 100% when all the files returned -1 when check the sizes. so I added this checking but since then it's showing Nan instead 0%

the first progressBarEx1 is working fine showing each file individual download progress.
the second progressBarEx2 should show the overall downloading progress.

[image: NaN]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Download_Webclient
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        private List<string> downloadLinks; // List of download links
        private int currentDownloadIndex; // Index of the current download
        private int totalBytesToReceive; // Total bytes to receive for all files

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            downloadLinks = new List<string>
            {
                "https://hil-speed.hetzner.com/100MB.bin",
                "https://hil-speed.hetzner.com/100MB.bin",
                "https://hil-speed.hetzner.com/100MB.bin",
                "https://hil-speed.hetzner.com/100MB.bin",
                // Add more links as needed
            };
        }

        private async void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
            using (var folderDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog())
            {
                // Show the FolderBrowserDialog
                DialogResult result = folderDialog.ShowDialog();

                // If the user selects a folder, start the downloads
                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    btnDownload.Enabled = false; // Disable to prevent multiple runs
                    progressBarEx1.Value = 0;
                    progressBarEx2.Value = 0;

                    totalBytesToReceive = 0;
                    foreach (string downloadLink in downloadLinks)
                    {
                        Uri uri = new Uri(downloadLink);
                        totalBytesToReceive += (int)await GetFileSizeAsync(uri);
                    }

                    if (totalBytesToReceive > 0)
                    {
                        progressBarEx2.Maximum = totalBytesToReceive; // Set maximum value for overall progress
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        progressBarEx2.Maximum = 0; // Set to 0 if unable to get file sizes
                    }

                    foreach (string downloadLink in downloadLinks)
                    {
                        Uri uri = new Uri(downloadLink);
                        string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderDialog.SelectedPath, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath));

                        using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
                        {
                            wc.DownloadProgressChanged += OnDownloadProgressChange;
                            wc.DownloadFileCompleted += OnDownloadFileComplete;

                            stopwatch.Start();
                            await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(uri, fileName);
                        }

                        currentDownloadIndex++;
                    }

                    lblProgress.Text = "All downloads complete!";
                    AdjustLabelPosition(lblProgress, progressBarEx1);
                    btnDownload.Enabled = true; // Restore availability of the download button
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task<long> GetFileSizeAsync(Uri uri)
        {
            try
            {
                using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, uri)))
                    {
                        if (response.Headers.Contains("Content-Length") &&
                            long.TryParse(response.Headers.GetValues("Content-Length").FirstOrDefault(), out long contentLength))
                        {
                            return contentLength;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                // Log or handle the exception as needed
                Console.WriteLine($"Error getting file size: {ex.Message}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle other types of exceptions if necessary
                Console.WriteLine($"An unexpected error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }

            // Return a default value if unable to get the file size
            return -1;
        }

        private void OnDownloadProgressChange(object sender, System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {   
            // Calculate progress values
            string downloadProgress = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
            string downloadSpeed = string.Format("{0} MB/s", (e.BytesReceived / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.00"));
            string downloadedMBs = Math.Round(e.BytesReceived / 1024.0 / 1024.0) + " MB";
            string totalMBs = Math.Round(e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024.0 / 1024.0) + " MB";

            // Format progress string
            string progress = $"{downloadedMBs}/{totalMBs} ({downloadProgress}) @ {downloadSpeed}";

            // Set values to controls
            lblProgress.Text = progress;
            AdjustLabelPosition(lblProgress, progressBarEx1);
            progressBarEx1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

            // Update overall progress
            long overallProgress = e.BytesReceived + progressBarEx2.Maximum * currentDownloadIndex;
            progressBarEx2.Value = (int)Math.Min(progressBarEx2.Maximum, overallProgress);
        }

        private void OnDownloadFileComplete(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                lblProgress.Text = $"Error downloading file: {e.Error.Message}";
            }
            else if (currentDownloadIndex < downloadLinks.Count)
            {
                lblProgress.Text = $"Downloading next file... ({currentDownloadIndex + 1}/{downloadLinks.Count})";
            }
            else
            {
                lblProgress.Text = "All downloads complete!";
            }

            AdjustLabelPosition(lblProgress, progressBarEx1);
            stopwatch.Reset();
        }

        private void AdjustLabelPosition(Label label, ProgressBar progressBar)
        {
            // Calculate the new Y position of the label
            int newY = progressBar.Top - label.Height - 5; // You can adjust the gap (5 in this case)

            // Calculate the new X position of the label to be in the middle of the progress bar
            int newX = progressBar.Left + (progressBar.Width - label.Width) / 2;

            // Set the new position for the label
            label.Location = new Point(newX, newY);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: progress = 100 * Value / Maximum.  I do see the code setting Maximum to 0, so division by zero is not unlikely.

Comment: [Updated the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77705986/7444103) to handle `float.NaN` on the Control's side. Returns `0` if `float.IsNaN(percentage)`