# How to modify the class of the progressBar that when changing the ForeColor and BackColor properties in design mode and runtime mode to take effect?

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I'm using the custom ProgressBar COntrol found here:

[How to show the progress percentage in the middle center of a ProgressBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77705335/7444103)

Now when I'm changing these properties it's not affecting the control not in design mode and not when running the application and I want it to affect the control in both design mode and/or runtime.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[ToolboxItem(true)]
public class ProgressBarEx : ProgressBar
{
    Color percentageColor = Color.Black;
    int percentageDecimals = 0;

    public ProgressBarEx()
    {

    }

    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Black")]
    public Color PercentageColor
    {
        get => percentageColor;
        set
        {
            if (percentageColor != value)
            {
                percentageColor = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    [DefaultValue(0), Description("Number of decimals (0-4)")]
    public int PercentageDecimals
    {
        get => percentageDecimals;
        set
        {
            if (percentageDecimals != value)
            {
                percentageDecimals = Math.Max(Math.Min(value, 4), 0);
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    // Override Font property to expose it in the property grid
    [Browsable(true)]
    public override Font Font
    {
        get => base.Font;
        set
        {
            base.Font = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_PAINT:
                if (!IsHandleCreated) return;
                float percentage = (float)Value / Maximum;
                var hDC = GetWindowDC(this.Handle);
                try
                {
                    using (var g = Graphics.FromHdcInternal(hDC))
                    {
                        TextRenderer.DrawText(g, percentage.ToString($"P{PercentageDecimals}"),
                            Font, ClientRectangle, PercentageColor);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (hDC != IntPtr.Zero) ReleaseDC(this.Handle, hDC);
                }
                m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    const int WM_PAINT = 0x000F;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDc);
}
```

Comment: Are you looking at the right control?  The posted code works for me.  I see a gray box with a 0% in the middle.

Comment: @LarsTech can you change the backcolor and forecolor in design mode of this progressBar ?  after dragging it to form1 designer.

Comment: You should know that you have to mention where the code you're showing comes from -- With Visual Styles enabled, you can only change the State of the standard ProgressBar, sending a [PBM_SETSTATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/pbm-setstate) message to the control. It only allows 3 states, which correspond to 1. Green, 2. Red, 3. Yellow. Otherwise, you have to paint over it. Which implies that you also have to dynamically adapt the color of the text when the ForeGround's brightness changes